# foo.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart --> Where can I change the holdoff time

Tags: systemd

I see this message in my logs:

```
systemd[1]: foo.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
```

I could not find the term "holdoff time" in here:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Where can I change the holdoff time?

Comment: Related systemd issue about improving the diagnostic wording: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5472

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `RestartSec` in the `[Service]` section.